# Оптимизация ajax запроса. Отваливается со временем. Нужны варианты

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Контекст:
Есть старый проект на jquery/php. Есть главная страница, где есть список пользователей онлайн. Раз в n-секунд(в моем случае 5) дергается ajax запрос, который получает с view-шки html код и вставляет в div(привожу просто для понимания:

```
(function update() {
                js.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/index.php?task=getListUsers&lastUserLogin=<?=filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'lastUserLogin', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)?>',
                    data: '',
                    success: function(data){                      
                        js('.right-column').html(data);
                        js('.top_block0 .jPushMenuBtn').show();
                        //console.log(data);
                        updateNumberUser();
                    }
                }).then(function() {// on completion, restart
                    setTimeout(update, right_column_update_time);// function refers to itself
                });

        })();
```

Страницу часто сворачивают во вкладке. ajax дергается до определенного момента успешно однако потом отваливается(ошибка 500 в консоли). 
Что я сделал:

1. определил что вкладка свернута или активна;
2. Пишу в куку статус;
3. Если вкладка стала активна,запускаю ajax, иначе не дергаю.

И это все работает однако через определенный период времени отваливается и приходится перезагружать страницу.

```
var vis = (function(){
        var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
    hidden: "visibilitychange",
    webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
    mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
    msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
        };
        for (stateKey in keys) {
    if (stateKey in document) {
        eventKey = keys[stateKey];
        break;
    }
        }
        return function(c) {
    if (c) {
        document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        //document.addEventListener("blur", c);
        //document.addEventListener("focus", c);
    }
    return !document[stateKey];
        }
    })();

    var status;
    vis(function(){
        status = vis() ? '1' : '0';
        console.log(new Date, 'visible ?', vis());
    });

    // to set the initial state
    status = vis() ? '1' : '0';

    js.cookie('ajax_status', status, {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    var ajax_status=js.cookie('ajax_status');


     if(ajax_status=='1'){ //функция выше }
```

Как заставить страницу работать и не отваливаться? Возможно код требует фундаментальной переработки и вообще избавления от этой ереси. Прошу помощи/совета JS-гуру)) Приходили на ум воркеры,чтобы не дергать DOM лишний раз однако я еще на практике их не "щупал".

Comment: Такие вещи принято делать на вебсокете. Если есть возможность - переделайте на него.

Comment: а что это даст?

Comment: Не будет ajax запросов по таймеру, соотвественно они не будут отваливаться))

Comment: ок, может так и сделаем. Однако возможно есть и проще решение?

Comment: Была похожая проблема. Нужно было приостановить интервал при ухода со вкладки. Решил через document.hidden. Самый простой способ - поставить проверку на открытость вкладки в начале функции интервала. Если вкладка не активна - ничего не делать.